# Why does passing this object through redirect_to call the `show` action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(params[:article])

  @article.save
  redirect_to @article
end

def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id]) 
end
```

I'm following the Getting Started with Rails guide. I have a form that, upon clicking the submit button, creates an `@article` object (a RESTful object) with the form input.

`redirect_to @article` sends a GET request to `/articles/id`, right? If so, why does this happen? Is this simply how `redirect_to` works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[redirect_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Redirecting/redirect_to) calls url_for if the argument passed is a Record.

[url_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/RoutingUrlFor/url_for) calls to_param on record which by default returns id.

Hence redirect_to @article will generate /articles/:id

Answer (score 1):

**Objects**

To add to `Nishu`'s answer, when you reference an object in *any* path_helper (`link_to`, `redirect_to` etc), Rails will do the hard work and show you the route for the **object**

Remember, Ruby / Rails is an [object-orientated](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_object_oriented.htm) framework, meaning everything you do has to revolve around an object. In the case of Rails, objects are populated with data from your models, which is done using `ActiveRecord`

--

So if you use `redirect_to @article`, Rails will basically look for the `show` action for that particular record. As your routes *should* be [resourceful](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) - meaning Rails can basically look for the relevant route to display that record on its own

Hope this helps?